# How to continue past error in SQL Script file in SSIS Package?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I've SSIS Package with me containing Execute SQL Task. This task invokes a SQL File and executes it against SQL Server.

In the script file, I've roughly 2000 statements, where any statement can fail depending on certain scenarios and other source input files.

In SSIS Package, for Execute SQL Task, I've set `MaximumErrorsCount` to `0` or even `5000`. THe problem is - this task stops as soon as first error occurs in SQL Script execution.

How should I upgrade the package so that SSIS tries next line in SQL file post errored line? I tried using Error Handler approach, but it didn't worked out.

[image: Execute SQL Task - Configured Properties]

Comment: _SSIS tries next line in SQL file post errored line_ This is not possible, SSIS has no concept of what line it's up to in the SQL Script. You're better off migrating your external SQL Script into a stored procedure and putting proper error handling in. Besides..... the idea of "if this line doesn't work just run the next one" sounds very bad from a data integrity view

Comment: Unless you have some kind of loop, 2000 statements inside a single batch is a bit of a code smell, and is at best a maintenance nightmare. I agree with Nick though, if you have specific scenarios where you expect a statement to fail, handle those specific scenarios and don't execute the statement, or at least handle the error. That may mean modifying 2,000 individual statements, and that is why this is a maintenance nightmare!

Comment: I agree with you both - but this a  migration scenario project and can't split it right now.

I figured out an intermediate solution - splitting string based on GO keyword and then processing each statement into a loop.